# Using OSSEC to monitor windows services

Tags: windows, logging, monitoring

I'm using `OSSEC` to trying and monitor services on servers such as `Windows Event Log`.

I would like to know if a service has stopped or started and get emailed accordingly.

I have tried a rule that alerts on event Id 6006 (The Event log service was stopped).

```
<rule id="100011" level="10">
        <match>INFORMATION(6006)</match>
        <options>alert_by_email</options>
        <description>The Event log service was stopped.</description>
</rule>
```

But this didn't fire on the event. So I tried testing the a log in *ossec-logtest*.

I had to make up the log entry as I was unable to get hold of the log that *ossec-analysisd* would process from `Windows's Event View`.

I tried the log in *ossec-logtest* and it seemed to firing ok.

**Input Log:**

```
2014 Sep 18 10:10:54 WinEvtLog: System: INFORMATION(6006): Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog: username: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: The Event log service was stopped.
```

**Ossec-logtest output:**

```
**Phase 1: Completed pre-decoding.
       full event: '2014 Sep 18 10:10:54 WinEvtLog: System: INFORMATION(6006): Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog: username: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: The Event log service was stopped.'
       hostname: 'CentOS1'
       program_name: '(null)'
       log: '2014 Sep 18 10:10:54 WinEvtLog: System: INFORMATION(6006): Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog: username: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: WIN-4HSALJIGG2H: The Event log service was stopped.'
**Phase 2: Completed decoding.
       No decoder matched.
**Phase 3: Completed filtering (rules).
       Rule id: '100011'
       Level: '10'
       Description: 'The Event log service was stopped.'
**Alert to be generated.
```

Which has lead me to think that the agents are not sending the log event 6006 to the OSSEC server. I am using the default configuration on the agent, is there anything I'm missing to get event ID 6006 to fire?